# SQL count rows in third table

Tags: mysql, sql

A row in **Table A** can be linked to many rows in **Table B**. A row in Table B will be linked to either one or zero rows in **Table C**.

For a given row in **Table A**, I would like to count the (indirectly) linked rows in **Table C**.

I would like to return this for each row in Table A. The below doesn't give any errors, but doesn't give the correct value.

```
SELECT
    *,
    (
        SELECT count(*)  
        FROM TABLE_A
        INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.foreignKeyA
        INNER JOIN TABLE_C ON TABLE_B.id = TABLE_C.foreignKeyB
    ) as cCount
FROM TABLE_A
```

**Sample data:**

TABLE_A

```
id
1
2
```

TABLE_B

```
id    foreignKeyA
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
```

TABLE_C

```
id    foreignKeyB
1     3
2     4
```

Should return (for the rows of Table A):

```
id    cCount
1     0
2     2
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  +

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I can't tell if you want each row in `C` in the result set or each row in `A`.

Comment: I added sample data, hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (SELECT count(*)  
        FROM TABLE_B b JOIN 
             TABLE_C c
             ON c.foreignKeyB = b.id
        WHERE b.foreignKeyA = a.id
    ) as aCount
FROM TABLE_A a;
```

Obviously, if you want the count for each row in `TABLE_C`, then you would adjust the table names and conditions.

You can do this with `JOIN`s, but you need outer joins and an overall aggregation.

Comment: Your code works as is, thank you!! I didn't need to change anything. I corrected my description. I wanted this for TABLE_A as you did, so there was no need for me to change any of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
> with table_count as (
    Select count(*) as cnt, TableB_FK
    From TableB B 
    JOIN TableA A on A.FK = B.FK
    Group By B.FK
)
select C.*, nvl(t.cnt,0)
from TableC C
left join table_count T on T.tableB_fk = C.FK
```

Table_count has aggregate count for foreign Keys.
Left Join table C with table count and replace null with 0

Comment: What is the difference between `TableB_FK` and `B.FK`?

Comment: Both are same. I used it for lack of better names

Answer (score 0):

Change the `INNER` joins to `LEFT` joins for the case there are not any linked rows to `TABLE_C`, in which case you want `0` as result:

```
SELECT TABLE_A.id, count(TABLE_C.id) cCount 
FROM TABLE_A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.foreignKeyA = TABLE_A.id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_C ON TABLE_C.foreignKeyB = TABLE_B.id
GROUP BY TABLE_A.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gDWP3mHyEsgHeg74FWEVHj/0).
Results:

```
| id  | cCount |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | 0      |
| 2   | 2      |
```